# Symfony Unique Entity error message not displaying

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've tried to implement the unique entity from Symfony and when I try to insert with same email, it doesn't show the error message, but it shows instead a PHP Error.

The error :

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (id, email, firstname, lastname, password, registered_at, is_verified, forgotten_password_token, forgotten_password_requested_at, farm_id, discr) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params ["8006dc22-226a-4fe1-b6f2-0baf0ac1767f", "producer@email.com", "Laurent", "Sanson", "$argon2id$v=19$m=65536,t=4,p=1$iKtkpJZhi\/SAAQDip2YTyQ$7n2+LRh8p+KQEN\/RzECrFDsxiouNAMyKuB6cdhMBIgY", "2021-01-05 19:53:36", 0, null, null, "478c39c3-12b3-4f0b-a877-b2d9edfbd6c5", "producer"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'producer@email.com' for key 'user.UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74'
```

The beginning of my UserClass :

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\UserRepository;
use DateTimeImmutable;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Serializable;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\EquatableInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\Uid\Uuid;

/**
 * Class User
 * @package App\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"producer"="App\Entity\Producer", "customer"="App\Entity\Customer"})
 * @UniqueEntity(
 *     fields="email",
 *     errorPath="email",
 *     message="Cet e-mail est déjà associé à un compte",
 *     entityClass="App\Entity\User"
 * )
 */
abstract class User implements UserInterface, Serializable, EquatableInterface
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="uuid")
     */
    protected Uuid $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(unique=true)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     * @Assert\Email
     */
    protected string $email = "";
}
```

I've tried many things but nothing seems to work

/// EDIT ///
The registration depends on the role but it'll be an user for sure. There is an inheritence between the User and the Customer/Producer
My RegistrationController :

```
/**
     * @Route("/register/{role}", name="app_register")
     * @param string $role
     * @param Request $request
     * @param UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder
     * @return Response
     */
    public function register(string $role, Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder): Response
    {
        $user = Producer::ROLE === $role ? new Producer() : new Customer();
        $user->setId(Uuid::v4());
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user, [
            "validation_groups" => ["Default" => "password"]
        ])->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            $user->setPassword(
                $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $user->getPlainPassword())
            );
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($user);
            $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
            $this->addFlash("success", "Votre inscription a été effectuée avec succès");

            return $this->redirectToRoute('index');
        }

        return $this->render('ui/security/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code that create your user

Comment: Hello, can you try to add @Assert\Unique assertion for email and validate it before trying to save? 
Best

Comment: you could also catch the exception on flush and render the error, but i would already in frontend check the availability of the entered email

Comment: @Mcsky No problem, I'll post it tonight

Comment: @l13 I'll try this tonight, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error in validation groups, it should be array of group like:

```php
['Default', 'password']
```

Answer (score 1):

So instead of

```
$form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user, [
            "validation_groups" => ["Default" => "password"]
        ])->handleRequest($request);
```

I should do like this ?

```
$form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user, [
            "validation_groups" => ["Default" , "password"]
        ])->handleRequest($request);
```

Comment: I've tried like this but it says that the User class does not exist... I'm desperate

Answer (score 1):

I've finally found it !!! :)

I had to remove the class param in the Unique entity annotation like :

```
 @UniqueEntity(fields="email", message="Cet e-mail est déjà associé à un compte")
```

Cheers guys !